# Contents section missing in New Java Project wizard

Tags: java, eclipse

Why is the Contents section (with the Create project from existing source option) sometimes missing in the Create a Java Project screen ?  I know I have seen and used it before but now it has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You better have to ask this question on the Eclipse JDT forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=13&

Comment: Can't register, can't ask questions on eclipse.org.  If you know the answer, please share it with me